# Paypal Developer Sandbox Accounts disappeared

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I created some sandbox test accounts from within my developer.paypal.com account last week. I have been using them for testing fine, and I have been able to get an overview of them, along with any email notifications they would've been receiving by going to developer.paypal.com and going to Applications -> Sandbox Accounts.

However, I have logged in today and they have disappeared. The default facilitator@ account is still there, and the number of total records suggests they are still there as it says 4, even though I only have 2 visible (the facilitator one and another I have just created now).

I can also still get access to each of the missing sandbox accounts directly at sandbox.paypal.com, but this gives me the merchant/buyer perspective rather than the developer overview.

Does anybody know how I can get these accounts back in?

Cheers,
Damian

Comment: I'm experiencing the same thing.  I created a new sandbox account last week (or maybe 2 weeks ago) and it's not showing up in my developer account anymore.  I can still log into it and use it just fine if I go directly to http://sandbox.paypal.com but it's not showing up in my developer account.  I posted a ticket to MTS about this and I've yet to hear anything back.

Comment: PayPal sandbox is a joke! It breaks 10 times every week. I don't know why it's difficult for a such a giant company to keep it up!